# Google App Engine Live Updates (Python)

Tags: python, ajax, google-app-engine

I was wondering if it would be possible to write an application using the Google App Engine and Python to create a basic calculator? However, the real question is would it be possible to have the calculator do the math without having to refresh the page?

To be more specific, I mean if there is an input box that a formula can be entered into (lets say for example the user inputs 2 + 2) and then the user clicks a submit button or calculate button, can the answer to the inputted problem be solved without the webpage having to refresh itself? If so, would it be possible to go about this without using AJAX? A very brief suggestion on how to go about this or a link to an application and its source code that updates things without refreshing the page would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: You know you could write such a calculator entirely in Javascript and never have to use a server at all, right?

Answer (score 0):

To make a calculator in a browser that does not involve a page refresh, your best bet is to learn javascript.  Searching google or stackoverflow for javascript tutorials will give you lots of options to work from.  You don't need to learn python or App Engine to create the calculator.  You could use app engine to serve the javascript, but you wouldn't need to write any python to just serve static content like that.

Answer (score 0):

Using GAE you provide a real-time update with "Channels" http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/

> The Channel API creates a persistent connection between your
>   application and Google servers, allowing your application to send
>   messages to JavaScript clients in real time without the use of
>   polling.

Interesting enough for your purpose.